# Domain of analyticity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let's say I have a function $f(z)$ =
\begin{cases}
 1/z^2&\text{if}\, z\neq 0\\
 1&\text{if}\, z= 0\\
\end{cases}

And I want to find the domain in which this function is analytic, at first sight, I notice that the limit as $z$ approaches 0 for $1/z^2$ is equal to $\infty$ and the function itself evaluated at 0 is equal to 1, so this function is discontinuous at $z$ = $0$ and so it must be non differentiable at $z$ = $0$

Using DeMovire's theorem, $1/z^2$ = $1/r^2$ (cos($2\theta$) - sin($2\theta$))

When I use the Cauchy Riemann equations in polar form:
$\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) = \frac{1}{r} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}\right) \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \right) = \frac{-1}{r} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)$

I find that the equations are satisfied at every point except at $r$ = $0$

Does this mean that this function is analytic in its whole domain except the origin? I just need some clarification, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: the limit $\lim_{z\to 0}z^{-2}$ doesnt exists, assuming that $z$ is complex. Note that in polar form $z^{-2}=r^{-2}e^{-it}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there is a simpler approach. Since the identity function is analytic, and since the product of two analytic functions is again analytic, the $z\mapsto z^2$ is analytic. Moreover, since $f$ analytic and without zeros $\implies\frac1f$ analytic, $z\mapsto\frac1{z^2}$ is analytic too (on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: Or, you can also calculate the derivative from first principles without much hassle.

Comment: @TheoBendit Can also determine whether $f$ lies in the kernel of $\overline{\partial}$.